# Why was my edit rejected even though it complies with the guidelines?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I read some posts about this question, and **still** it doesn't make sense that my edit suggestion was rejected.

**Posts that I read:**

- [Why was my edit rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164448/why-was-my-edit-rejected)
- [Why was my suggested edit rejected repeatedly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192469/why-was-my-suggested-edit-rejected-repeatedly)
- [Why was suggested edit rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142155/why-was-suggested-edit-rejected)
- [Why was my suggested edit rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164101/why-was-my-suggested-edit-rejected)

---

**Here is my suggested edit:**

[image: Suggested edit]

**My goal** with this edit was, to give the post a **better** look. Make it simpler for users to recognize code functions, properties... That's even **exactly what an edit should be** (according to the answers to the questions mentioned above).

I am really intersted to know why this edit was rejected, because if I did a mistake with this suggestion, I want to avoid this mistakes in the near future.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suggestion was rejected automatically. Read the message for the reason of rejection:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

A user with full edit privileges made an edit while your suggestion was still pending. In these cases, the non-reviewed edit overrides the suggestion, thus making Community reject it as "conflicted with a subsequent edit".