# I assume I am following guidelines, so why was my edit rejected? What did I miss?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Well, my recent two edits have been rejected.
And I have already went through *already answered* similar questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208823/what-can-i-do-when-my-edit-was-rejected-unjustified) & [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326038/why-was-my-edit-rejected-even-though-it-complies-with-the-guidelines).

And after reading above two links, I understood that there are set of rules/guidelines which one should abide/follow while editing a Question or an Answer over all meta network sites. And these are separately documented on each network site , for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) as well.

Now please see this situation, I have received Review rights [Custodian] recently as I moved to 500+ reputation few weeks before and as I was trying to explore the new privilege thus helping new users while they answer or ask question.

Now, when you do this, you see the below guidelines:

[image]

After reading this I got an immediate impression on how can I contribute, and I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22664265) edit, in this if you see the original answer and the guidelines in above screenshot then:

- Vote up or down to rate the answer's helpfulness ( Though answer was making a point but failed to relate to OP.So, I can't vote up)
- **Edit to improve the answer's appearance, clarity, or accuracy** (*That's the best option I had and I did this*).
- Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up
  existing comments (*This was the 3rd in hierarchy and for this particular scenario I thought its better to edit rather a comment, so that First timer will learn from the edited answer & he'll know how to answer on SO. Personally, I also learnt same way*).
- Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems (Not applicable)

Same way for this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22664211): if you see I amended the label of the question which will help other to search this question as well as added exception in the question which was there in comments so that it is spread widely. Yet this is rejected.

#### My take on this:

As I went through other answers to similar question, I came to know that edits should be done as per [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) guidelines (when you got 2000+).

However, for a first timer 500+ (Custodian badge) the first impression we get are on above (screenshot) review guidelines.
And when it is reviewed by senior members of SO then then they take [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) guidelines in context and resulting in rejected edits.

Thus, I think rules/guidelines should be made in sync at both the places for all the meta sites.

Looking for more opinions, please advise.

Comment: Completely rewriting an answer isn't what edits are for.  The second one is better; not sure why that one was rejected.

Comment: _Completely rewriting an answer isn't what edits are for_ , I completely agree but one also cannot take the essence/solution/suggestion of a newcomer and make it as a seperate answer? Then did review helped ? No right? As end goal to make new-comer understand what he was missing..

Comment: One *can* take the essence of an answer, newcomer or not, and make it a separate answer, sure.  In fact, that is what one *should* do, and credit the source when doing so if it helped you.  Editing an answer that drastically goes counter to the purpose of editing.  If you want to educate the newcomer, you can comment on their answer with what they are missing.

Comment: Hmm, got your point and agree to it. One should credit the source if it helped but as a seperate answer. Then I think SO should amend wordings of review guidelines for custodian badge holders, rather promoting to edit, importance should be more on other 3. What do you think? Lastly, there should be some mechanism to challenege the rejection, even in my first edit I never changed anything **drastically** ...

Comment: Editing is still a good thing to do.  But you need to recognize what editing is for; it's not meant to change what the author is saying.  This is why those under 2K rep need to have them reviewed, so they have that time to understand when and how to edit.  And, no, there shouldn't be a way to challenge rejections; it takes two people to reject, and while they can make mistakes, they are more trusted than you.  Your first edit was a **massive** change.  It wasn't an edit; it was a rewrite, exactly not what to do for edits.

Comment: All the questions/answers I read before writing my question were asked on this very meta site, how come this is off-topic and they're not? Most recent one is just 5 days ago asked here on this meta site.
What should I do, delete and post there on SO?

Comment: Please, read the close reason.  That's why it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original answer in [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22664265) is so low-quality that your edit basically turns it into a new answer. That's why the rejection reason

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

applies. It's better just to post a new answer with all the content you added, cf. the last sentence of the other rejection reason:

> It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

(maybe with a note that you're expanding on @Umn23bra's answer, that would be nice). As a bonus, you'll probably get more reputation from a full-fledged answer than the +2 you would get for an approved suggested edit.

The second edit you mention should have been approved, IMHO.

For your information, here are the guidelines in the Suggested Edits review queue:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel for your answer. At first , even I thought to add as an answer however then I realise might be it is not eithical , since I will be using essence of original answer and enhancing it & adding. And SO guidelines advise to edit to enhance rather add as through edit we basically enhance so that original answer-person understand and learn for future. What do you think?

Comment: Also really thanks for _the guidelines in the Suggested Edits review queue_ .

Comment: You're welcome. Good that you're worried about ethics; attribution should cover that. Otherwise, I'd say your content is *inspired* by the other answer, it's a lot more than just *enhancing* it.

Comment: +1 another way or gentleman way of putting it :), Anyways I understood. However, I still feel there should be little wordings change or a link to a page demostrating sample edits. I don't have stats but can imagine how many might have chosen to edit rather add just because it is in the guidelines.

Comment: If it is any consolation to you, I often make relatively minor edits from the First Posts / Late Answers as well. Having them rejected is unfortunate but I guess it just comes with the job. Just like you're sometimes posting a decent answer but it doesn't get the attention it might deserve. (That compensates for the simple answers that get a gazillion upvotes because they're on the Hot Network Questions list, but I digress...)